Why I can't see all the sites I'm owner of when I try to copy a list in sharepoint?
I'm an (invited) owner of a sharepoint site collection. I would like to copy a list from there to another site, because I need a lookup column. Apparently I can use a list for lookup only if that list is under the same site collection so I need a copy or to move it.
I have tried to make a new list from an existing one, but this new site is not among those I can choose from (although I'm an owner). I don't understand why though. What am I doing wrong?

I can see all sites (have permission) in "Select an existing list" popup while creating a list from existing list option on our SharePoint tenant.

Try below options:

Check if you still have permissions on site to want to use - in case someone else managing permissions for sites.

Try "following" the site where your source list is created


Open the Site Contents page of the SharePoint site (site X) that has the existing lists. On the top right side, you'll see an option to follow the site with a star. select this option.
Once done, now if you go to a new SP site and click on create list from existing list, you'll be able to see the  lists from site X.

I have downvoted for extremely persistent vote begging. This kind of fluff will always be removed from your questions, and it adds to the workload of editors. Again, please refrain from adding it.
